# Angular 2 test dependencies

Tags: angular, karma-runner, angular-cli

I'm trying to test components with an Angular 2, but am having trouble with loading dependencies.

I'm getting a Karma error when I try to import the `UserModule` when testing `UserShowcaseComponent`, and if I don't import it I get a lot of missing component errors.

The test setup is what angular-cli generates and my specific test is the following

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { UserModule } from '../../user.module';
import { UserShowcaseComponent } from './user-showcase.component';

describe('UserShowcaseComponent', () => {
    let component: UserShowcaseComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<UserShowcaseComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [UserModule],     <---------------------------------- NOTE
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(UserShowcaseComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

The error from Karma is simply this (this is the full output, no tests are run):

```
29 11 2016 16:49:40.478:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.2.0 server started at http://localhost:9876/
29 11 2016 16:49:40.479:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
29 11 2016 16:49:40.649:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
29 11 2016 16:49:42.010:INFO [Chrome 53.0.2785 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#Jpv1IioGnou6CQtUAAAA with id 98117142
Chrome 53.0.2785 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Karma was not loading vendor files, and this was not being reported properly. This reporting issue has been fixed as of `angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.20`, see [this commit](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/f09439c).

The solution is to add vendor libs in `karma.conf.js`, in my case adding

```
{ pattern: './node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', watched: false }
```

to `files`.

Yes, I know i should not be using jquery.